# Nuxt fetch data with vuex action but return undefined in store getters

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I am facing a problem with my fetch with actions of store returning undefined

component.js

```
export default: {
...
async fetch({ store, route }) {
    await store.dispatch('calendar/getDetailSportingEvents', {
      type: route.params.context,
      id: route.params.id
    })
  },
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    data: 'calendar/getData' //loads in server side but on client it returns {}
  })
 }
...
}
```

store/calendar.js

```
const state = () = ({
 data: {}
})

const getters = {
 getData(state) {
  return state.data
 }
}

const mutations = {
 updateData(state,payload) {
  state.data = payload
 }
}

const actions = {
  async getDetailSportingEvents(context, {type, id}) {
      try {
        const data = await this.$axios
          .$get(`apiUrlString`)
          await context.commit('setCalendarEvent', data)
      } catch (err) {
      }
    }
}

export default { state, getters, mutations, actions }
```

It manages to call on server side as I can see the logs that the data is being passed through and there is a render of the content. However after a second when the app is fully loaded, it just disappears cause the mapGetters from returning payload data to just default which is {} which I have a `v-if` to check if the return value is `null` or empty `Object`

The reason why I have it set up like so, because I have a refresh button that will call `this.$fetch()` method for the latest data

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your **store/calendar.js** the *getDetailSportingEvents* action in the store, it's committing a mutation called "setCalendarEvent" but in your mutations, there only exists a mutation called "updateData", so, maybe have a look at your code? I dunno, I'm just going with what you posted.

Comment: I have a form of a workaround. The idea is to put all the available api call on the store section of the app so it is an easier reference and acts as documentation. What needs to happen is the store needs to have a return in action function and the states to only handle loading/endOfList for example.

Comment: There is also a function that you can call `fetchOnServer: false` to do those call when the app has been loaded. then only put it on state after